# Trigger event after selecting datalist option

Tags: javascript, html-datalist

Is there a way to trigger a JavaScript event specifically after selecting a datalist option? **By that I don't mean if any input has been entered, or even if an input identical to an option in the datalist has been typed in manually.**

I only want it to trigger if you specifically CLICK the option from the datalist displayed.

I tried `$('#search-data').click()` and `$('#search-data options').click()`, but neither triggered.

```js
$('#search-options').click(function(){
  alert("test");
});

$('#search-options options').click(function(){
  alert("test 2");
});
```

```html
<datalist id="search-options">
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
</datalist>

<input id="search-bar" type="text" list="search-options" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If you don't mind, please reproduce on codesandbox.

Comment: @VictorL. I'm not sure what you wanted me to reproduce, but I suppose I added the relevant code as a snippet

Comment: I think you can use change event of input. - @alex

Comment: @VictorL. but the change event detects any change, not only change from the datalist

Comment: Of course, but I think you can't add any event listener to datalist options, so you need to use input change event. If you want, I can show you how it works. - @alex

Comment: @VictorL. I know how to add a change event to the input, however unless there is a way to determine whether the change came specifically from clicking the datalist or not, it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to check if any input has been entered, or if an input identical to an option in the datalist has been typed in manually, you can try this.

```js
var textbox = document.getElementById("search-bar");
textbox.addEventListener(
  "input",
  function (e) {
    var isInputEvent =
      Object.prototype.toString.call(e).indexOf("InputEvent") > -1;
    // If the type is not InputEvent, then an option was selected from the datalist
    if (!isInputEvent) alert(e.target.value);
  },
  false
);
```

```html
<datalist id="search-options">
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
</datalist>

<input id="search-bar" type="text" list="search-options" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
```

This solution uses the input event and checks the type of the event object. If the type is not InputEvent, then it means that **the input event was caused by a datalist option selection, not by keyboard input, mouse input, or paste input**. By using this approach, you can trigger a JavaScript event specifically after selecting a datalist option.

Comment: unfortunately this also triggers when manually entering text identical to the datalist option, which as i've mentioned in my original question, is not what I'm looking for :(

Thank you anyways, though!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated my answer for your purpose. please check it - @alex

Comment: @VictorL. Not sure, but it seems like it doesn't do anything in both cases?

Comment: Umm, on my computer, it works fine. but if you can't see anything, that's so weird. - @SallylovesLightning

Comment: I'm using Firefox. That's the problem I guess. Try your code in Firefox browser.

Comment: this mostly works and its a lot simpler than my solution. It fails to trigger the alert if the current value of the input is the same as the option you clicked, otherwise it seems to work

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comment. - @chiliNUT, it's also not working in firefox. I'm not sure but I think firefox prevents such input event.

Answer (score 2):

So the issues are:

1. You can't target the options with selectors
2. The change/input events will fire regardless of if the input was changed from the keyboard, clipboard, or picking an option

I added a bunch of listeners to a datalist: `keyup, keydown, paste, input, change` and observed the following:

Clicking on an item in the datalist triggers a keyup event with an empty (undefined) keycode, followed by whatever other events are related to the input changing, followed by a keydown event with an empty keycode.

Pasting will trigger a paste event, typing will trigger a key event that is non-undefined. So create a listener for all of the events, and then check whenever we see this pattern:

```
    undefined keydown 
    + (input and change event when value changed OR no event when value did not change)
    + undefined keyup
```

Log each heard event in an array, and then check the array for a valid chain.

**Disclaimer**
This seems to work, but its hacky, subject to breaking, and only tested in chrome

```js
let eventQueue = [];
let foundKeydown = false;
const $search = $('#search-bar');
$search.on('paste change input keyup keydown', event => {
// if the event type is not keyup or keydown, log it
    if (event.type !== 'keyup' && event.type !== 'keydown') {
        eventQueue.push(event.type);
    }
    if (event.type === 'keydown' && !event.keyCode) {
        // drop everything prior in the eventQueue. 
        //this is the start of a potential option click
        eventQueue = [];
        foundKeydown = true;
    }
    if (event.type === 'keyup' && !event.keyCode && foundKeydown === true) {
        // this is the end of a potential click.
        foundKeydown = false;
        // check that the queue contains:
        if (
            // 1. no paste or key events
            eventQueue.every(type => type !== 'paste' && type !== 'keyup' && type !== 'keydown')
            // and
            && (
                // 1. either an input+change event
                (eventQueue.some(type => type === 'change') && eventQueue.some(type => type === 'input'))
                // or neither
                || eventQueue.every(type => type !== 'change' && type !== 'input')
            )
        ) {
            console.log('clicked a data option:', event.target.value);
        }

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<datalist id="search-options">
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
</datalist>
<input id="search-bar" type="text" list="search-options">
```

Comment: Fantastic, your code works fine. but it's also not working in Firefox. do you know the reason? If you know, please let me know.

Comment: ff doesnt emit the empty keyup/keydown events so thats why it doesn't work. FF's "chain" seems to be `click+beforeinput+input+selectionchange` but its not consistent

Comment: first of all: Thank you very much! It doesn't seem to work with firefox, as Victor L. mentioned, but I very much appreciate the insight and experimenting that went into this! I'll see if I can go on from this to see if I can figure out a solution that works with Firefox as well!